# linux system release WebService server failure

Tags: linux, web-services, tomcat, java-6

System was released in linux + tomcat5.5.33 + jdk1.6_45 + java, wherein the system in time to start the server release webService error, as shown below:
[image]

Code is as follows

```
Endpoint.publish(PUBParm.FS_WS_ADDRESS_URL +"/BQFT/fs?wsdl", new CifServiceImpl());
```

---

```
package service.service;
```

@WebService
public interface CifService {

```
public String testFsInter(String str);

@WebMethod(operationName = "findByDate")
public String findByDate(@WebParam(name="strDate")String strDate) throws Exception;

@WebMethod(operationName = "findByDateBean")
public List<CifInfo> findByDateBean(@WebParam(name="strDate")String strDate) throws Exception;
```

}

---

```
package service.service.impl;
```

@WebService(endpointInterface = "service.service.CifService", targetNamespace = "http://fs.service/", serviceName = "FsService", portName = "FsPort")
public class CifServiceImpl implements CifService{

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "findByDate")
public String findByDate(@WebParam(name = "strDate") String txDate){
    ......
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(cifInfoList);
    ......
    return json;
}

@WebMethod(operationName = "findByDateBean")
public List<CifInfo> findByDateBean(@WebParam(name = "strDate") String txDate){
    .......
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(cifInfoList);

    ......
    return cifInfoList;
}

@WebMethod(operationName = "testFsInter")
public String testFsInter(String str){
    return str +"ok!";
}
```

}

---

Project in the windows environment can start and release. Will this may be why, and how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved, but since the operation too much, only suspected war package in question, or Jar package conflicts related to the project in tuscany, but the personal feeling of great might -line war issues